# Two native mobile applications sharing same Azure AD B2C (Configuration)

Tags: android, azure, xamarin.forms, azure-ad-b2c

I have two **Native Android** applications, that uses the same Azure AD B2C Application.

I have created the first application with the below code in my android manifest

```
<activity android:name="microsoft.identity.client.BrowserTabActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="msauth-74ffd02e-dc15-4e4b-bec8-966579b851db" android:host="com.myapp.firstadapplication" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

If my understanding is correct, this piece of code uniquely identifies the application after the login has succeeded. Especially the **android scheme**.

In the Azure AD portal I have configured the same scheme in **redirect uri**
[image]

```
msauth-74ffd02e-dc15-4e4b-bec8-966579b851db://com.myapp.firstadapplication
```

**Here my doubt is,**

Since I am using the same Azure AD application in my two native mobile applications,
Is it possible to add another redirect uri, in the Azure portal that uniquely identifies the second app? Something like what I have written below.

For First application  -

```
msauth-74ffd02e-dc15-4e4b-bec8-966579b851db://com.myapp.firstadapplication
```

For Second application -

```
msauth-64ffd02e-ec15-3e4b-bec8-866579b851db://com.myapp.secondadapplication
```

Comment: did you fix it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think what you are describing is possible. Any authentication would require a unique Application ID/Client ID for the token to be stored and the users to be validated against the application. The AD users are given access to the applications within the AD tenant.

Comment: In portal I can see the option to add multiple re-direct uris. So what could be the use of that?

Comment: Also, Are you telling that, 2 different native app cannot integrate into the same Azure AD b2c Application?

Comment: Not if you are validating and SSOing users separately against these applications.

Comment: Let me ask one last doubt, I can see provision to add multiple redirect uris in azure portal. What is the use for that'